# Attack on Weierstrass Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, montgomery-multiplication

I have a naive question(as non specialist in this field).

While reading Weierstrass Curve description,I found that it turns into 2 periodic tori on 2D complex plane. 
Is is it possible to create fast multiplication attack on this curve by implementing this transformation into tori on complex plain - like 2D clock multiplication by decomposing numbers into two dimention on complex plane? 
Here is something similar to this

- [Elliptic Curves Lecture #17](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2017/LectureNotes17.pdf)
- [Complex Multiplication: Lecture 5](http://math.columbia.edu/~yihang/CMTutorial/notes%209-22%20s.pdf%20Thanx)